# Subdomains routing with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, subdomain

There's a solution to create routes for subdomains with AngularJS?

I searched on google and many others and I cant solve this problem.

I want do like "http://minetop.net/serverName"

```
app.config(function($routeProvider)
{

    $routeProvider

    .when('/:serverID', {
        templateUrl : '../design/template/pages/server.html',
        controller  : 'srvCtrl'
    })          

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '../design/template/pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainCtrl'
    }); 

});
```

But I want do this with subdomains, example : http://serverName.minetop.net

PS : "serverName" is dynamic.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It seems pretty standard and the goog has nothing. :(

Comment: Did you find enything? I am having the same issue and can't find the solution

Comment: Hey, no I havent found a solution... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as far as the Angular router is concerned subdomains are not even a part of your app.  In order to redirect to a subdomain you need to do a few things.

1) modify the /private/etc/hosts file to include the subdomain.  From the command line

```
sudo vi /private/hosts/etc
```

then add the subdomain next to your localhost alias.  This will allow your local resolve the subdomain to your app

2) create a route filter that will do a redirect to your subdomain given certain conditions.  In order to actually redirect just use

```
myRedirectionFilter = function(){
if("foo" !== "bar"){
 window.location.href = "http://serverName.minetop.net"}
}
```

3) use the filter in the resolve function in your routes.js file.

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : '../design/template/pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainCtrl',
    resolve: myRedirectionFilter()
});
```